# Are the Dungeon Siege games story driven?

Tags: dungeon-siege

Hope it's on topic: I'm wondering what kind of game the Dungeon Siege games are - are they Story heavy like Baldur's Gate, Dragon Age or Neverwinter Nights?

Or are they more action grinders with a light story and focus on re-playability through map generation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dungeon Siege has far more in common with Diablo II with regards to gameplay and story.

Comment: Yeah, loose story with more of a 'Go to here and speak to X', que mincing mobs all the way there :D

Comment: if i remember the first Dungeon Seige was a little more forward moving. It did not have you returning to hub towns too often to turn in quests as most of the quests were designed to move you forward to the next town.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to the games you mentioned, the story for this series, is quite loose.

The best story they have, is in *Dungeon Siege II*. I'll give a 75/100 for this.

*Dungeon Siege III* is more focusing on action gameplay than story. And though it has a short story, the different characters you could play have quite different gameplay experiences.